# RStudio Server in Windows WSL2 - Shiny Server: What is the difference:

Tags: r, shiny-server, self-hosting, rstudio-server

This may be a very basic question for guys who handle daily with programming issues!

And until today I was not able to find the right words to ask and now I hope I can explain clearly what I want!

It is technically not a coding question!
It is not flagged with a reproducible example!

But I can't grasp it and decided to seek for advice here.

The story behind:

1. My ultimate goal was and is to build a database (CRUD) where we can fill it over the net.
   I mastered meanwhile all of the hurdles and
2. I started with Rshiny and sqlite and finally build the app!
3. Now when it comes to store this app on a server, I learned things about persistent data storage etc...
4. To store the app on shinyapps.io was not a good idea, because here the saved files disappear depending on which server is active.
5. Next I successfully installed RStudio server with this tutorital https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049776974-Using-RStudio-Server-in-Windows-WSL2 on my computer.
6. I thought to publish the app on this server. But if I access I get a rstudio environment...
7. Then I find shiny server https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shiny-server.html...

My question: What is the difference between RStudio Server and Shiny Server.

Is there any resource which could bring me further.

Really I appreciate any directing help!

Answer (score 1):

It is as the name suggests:

- **RStudio** server serves a RStudio, that can then be accessed via a web browser.
- **Shiny server** is a web and compute server that serves shiny apps.

So you need definitely a shiny server. Installation is quite simple, see https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/ but the free version misses https, load balancing and authentification. These features (and more) are available in the commercial version, but it is also possible to use an addional reverse proxy with Apache or Nginx to provide these services with the free version.